# How can I Insert another Widget in place of another when one is pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am an entry level flutter developer and I've been stuck for a while on this problem, I've tried different things

I am try to make the 'Note Title' (that particular widget), pop out

[The app_issue description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnNMc.gif)

then this should show instead
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAa2i.png)

The two different content under the "My Notes" tab are two Stateful Widgets and the "My Notes" tab is another Stateful Widget on its own

I've tried using a function but it doesn't work

```
enum MyNoteContent {
  staticNote,
  dynamicNote,
}

MyNoteContent selectedContent = MyNoteContent.staticNote;

Widget updateMyNotes() {
  if (selectedContent == MyNoteContent.staticNote) {
    return MyNoteStatic();
  } else {
    return MyNoteDynamic();
  }
}
```

and then i call the function in the MyNotes Widget

```
class _MyNotesTabState extends State<MyNotesTab> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return updateMyNotes();
  }
}
```

I trying to update the value in the first content that is shown (in its own Widget), so that when it is pressed, it should change

```
class _MyNoteStaticState extends State<MyNoteStatic> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RawMaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedContent = MyNoteContent.dynamicNote;
              updateMyNotes();
            });
          },
```

but it does not work

[Code to Reproduce the Problem](https://gist.github.com/davidnwaneri/2794f7c388f875409c87c255bdaa93a3)

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's a bit unclear what the code you actually have now is. Make something that we can paste into Dartpad and shows the problem.

Comment: I just added it. It's a link to GitHubGist.

Comment: Paste the full example directly into your question and try and remove as much extraneous code as possible.

Comment: setState doesn't affect other widgets!

Comment: @Yadu That's not very accurate. Calling `setState` in a child cannot directly affect a parent, but reversing it will create an effect.

Comment: I'll rephrase it, setState is a function which belongs to State class, when called it'll will rebuild the state of the Widget it belongs to, it might rebuild the children but it will definitely not rebuild the parent, unless you find a way like @ChristopherMoore answered to rebuild parent from feedback from the child

Comment: @Yadu I think I get the logic now. Thank you contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the `setState` you're calling is for the `_MyNoteStaticState` class. This means it will only rebuild the `MyNoteStatic` widget. But in order for the page to change you need to rebuild its parent `_MyNotesTabState`. So you need to call the `setState` method of `_MyNotesTabState` which can be done by passing a callback down from `_MyNotesTabState` to `_MyNoteStaticState`.

First, move `updateMyNotes` & `selectedContent` into the `_MyNotesTabState` class since that's the only place they're needed.

Make a new function that rebuilds `_MyNotesTabState` and changes `selectedContent` in `_MyNotesTabState`.

```dart
void changeNote() {
  setState(() {
    selectedContent = MyNoteContent.dynamicNote;
  });
}
```

Pass it down to `MyNoteStatic`

```dart
Widget updateMyNotes() {
  if (selectedContent == MyNoteContent.staticNote) {
    return MyNoteStatic(changeNote);
  } else {
    return MyNoteDynamic();
  }
}
```

and modify `MyNoteStatic` to accept this callback as a parameter

```dart
class MyNoteStatic extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback callback;
  MyNoteStatic(this.callback);

  @override
  _MyNoteStaticState createState() => _MyNoteStaticState();
}
```

Then pass this callback to your button instead of what you currently have:

```dart
child: RawMaterialButton(
  onPressed: widget.callback,
)
```

Full relevant code incorporating the above changes:

```dart
enum MyNoteContent {
  staticNote,
  dynamicNote,
}

class MyNotesTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyNotesTabState createState() => _MyNotesTabState();
}

class _MyNotesTabState extends State<MyNotesTab> {
  MyNoteContent selectedContent = MyNoteContent.staticNote;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return updateMyNotes();
  }
  
  Widget updateMyNotes() {
    if (selectedContent == MyNoteContent.staticNote) {
      return MyNoteStatic(changeNote);
    } else {
      return MyNoteDynamic();
    }
  }
  
  void changeNote() {
    setState(() {
      selectedContent = MyNoteContent.dynamicNote;
    });
  }
}

//Static Note
class MyNoteStatic extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback callback;
  MyNoteStatic(this.callback);

  @override
  _MyNoteStaticState createState() => _MyNoteStaticState();
}

class _MyNoteStaticState extends State<MyNoteStatic> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RawMaterialButton(
          onPressed: widget.callback,
...
```

Comment: @davidn Also please try to edit your code directly into your question so that this may better benefit future users.